ASP.NET + Angular application on NGINX and EC2 working fine... but when using certificates from ACM and ALB giving error re-routing application to ASP
I have my ASP.NET and Anguular working fine on EC2, for making my domain HTTPS , I need certificates, using ACM , I got the certificates and I had to apply it on my domain using the ALB which calls EC2 and EC2 should call NGINX and NGINX should redirect to ASP API Calls... I tried changing the nginx file , changing the baseUrl for ASP it doesnt go through....
When I was just on EC2, my baseUrl was IP_of_EC2:5000( ASP was listening on 5000) and in NGINX the proxy pass was : http://localhost:5000, it worked perfectly...
when I moved to ALB/my domain... this calls started failing.
So I want to change my NGINX and baseURL... any suggesttions are really appreciated...
I tried all combinations like

changing url of asp from http to https
changing the baseUrl to domain/alb/ec2
changing the proxy_pass to domain/alb/ec2

It either gives me too many redirects or 405 error or mixed content errror
